# The constructor RuleViolation(ParameterNameConvention, int, String, RuleContext) is undefined

Tags: pmd

Thanks.

```
public class ParameterNameConvention extends AbstractJavaRule {

private final static String PATTERN = "[p][a-zA-Z]+";

public Object visit(ASTMethodDeclaration node, Object data) {
    RuleContext result = (RuleContext) data;
    String rulePattern = (!getStringProperty("rulePattern")
            .equalsIgnoreCase("")) ? getStringProperty("rulePattern")
            : PATTERN;
    if (node.containsChildOfType(ASTFormalParameter.class)) {
        Iterator iterator = node.findChildrenOfType(
                ASTFormalParameter.class).iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            ASTFormalParameter element = (ASTFormalParameter) iterator
                    .next();
            Iterator decIdIterator = element.findChildrenOfType(
                    ASTVariableDeclaratorId.class).iterator();
            while (decIdIterator.hasNext()) {
                ASTVariableDeclaratorId decElement = (ASTVariableDeclaratorId) decIdIterator
                        .next();
                if (!decElement.getImage().matches(rulePattern)) {

                    result.getReport()
                            .addRuleViolation(
                                    new RuleViolation(
                                            this,
                                            node.getBeginLine(),
                                            "Parameter '"
                                                    + decElement.getImage()
                                                    + "' should match regular expression pattern '"
                                                    + rulePattern + "'",
                                            result));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

For the `new RuleViolation` there is a problem:

> The constructor RuleViolation(ParameterNameConvention, int, String, RuleContext) is undefined

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of PMD are you using?  IN PMD 4.2.5, the constructors for [RuleViolation](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.2.5/apidocs/net/sourceforge/pmd/RuleViolation.html) are:

```
RuleViolation(Rule rule, RuleContext ctx, SimpleNode node) 

RuleViolation(Rule rule, RuleContext ctx, SimpleNode node, java.lang.String specificMsg)
```

Your code doesn't match either of these.

Comment: Thanks. I have finished this part of work. All the problems are the problem of version. And now I am going to begin another part. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's just the problem of version. Thanks.